# using ffmpeg to convert raw audio data to wav file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav

I have a text file that contains some raw data that I generated from a wav file. I read in a signal from the wav file, and then used

`fid = open("test.raw", 'write')
fid.write(data.tostring())`

to write the raw data to a file. Currently, I'm doing this because I want to be able to append to this file as needed without having to change header information. I'm not concatenating multiple audio files, just processing parts of a signal and I don't want to have a potentially enormous signal in memory. When I try to use ffmpeg to convert this data using

`ffmpeg -i test.raw output.wav`

I end up getting the error: `test.raw: Invalid data found when processing input`. I've also been going through the ffmpeg docs but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

Comment: Do you get corrupt file even when you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: `fid = open("test.raw", 'wb')` else your data gets the linefeed replacement treatment (if you're using windows)

Comment: Yep, it still happens even if I'm using `fid = open("test.raw", 'wb')`